# Redundant classname references in Python

Tags: python, oop, python-import

My python program has the following structure

```
projectfolder
|--classes
   |--__init__.py
   |--Exampleclass.py
|--singletons
   |--__init__.py
   |--Examplesingleton.py
__init__.py
Main.py
```

Basically, in my main class, I want to create several instances of Exampleclass.py (and other classes from the folder classes) and put them inside an instance of Examplesingleton.py (basically the "World" that is populated by the instances of classes).

The problem is, I always have to call Examplesingleton and Exampleclass like this:

Main.py

```
import singletons.Examplesingleton as Examplesingleton
import classes.Exampleclass as Exampleclass

test = Exampleclass.Exampleclass("test")
Examplesingleton.Examplesingleton.Exampleclasses.append(test)
```

Is there a way in Python to reference these classes without typing the Class name twice?

Instead of

```
Exampleclass.Exampleclass()
```

I want to write just

```
Exampleclass()
```

I tried using

```
from classes.Exampleclass import Exampleclass
```

seems to enable that but leads to circular import error messages.

Exampleclass.py:

```
class Exampleclass:

    Somevariable = 0

    def __init__(self, somevariable):
        self.Somevariable = somevariable
```

Examplesingleton.py:

```
class Examplesingleton(object):

    Exampleclasses = []

    @classmethod
    def __init__(cls):
        pass
```

Comment: `from singletons.Examplesingleton import Examplesingleton`?

Comment: I tried using that but it leads to circular import error messages.

Comment: You can't get circular imports unless the module also has its own import statements.

Comment: what messages, specifically, on what line for what import? Please provide a minimal code sample, showing the problem *and including the full file contents*. Also, Python is not Java you don't a file per class.

Comment: also an `__init__` constructor shouldn't be getting `@classmethod` decorator.

Comment: You probably get the circular import because the module has the same name as the class. Try lowercase filenames.